# Notepad++ highlight occurrences of selected text

Tags: notepad++

I know that I can double click a word and Notepad++ will highlight all instances of that word within the document. My question is **not** about this.

Does anyone know of a plug-in or setting which will allow me to select as many characters as I please and highlight all occurrences of those characters?

Given the following text file:

```
$hey_you = 'hey you';
$hey_me = 'hey me';
$hey_we = 'hey we';
```

With my cursor I wish to select `$hey_` and have the 3 `$hey_`s highlighted.

---

Also, if the scroll-bar could behave like Google Chrome's with yellow markings then that would be a huge bonus, too.

[image]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try the Settings -> Preferences -> Highlighting and uncheck the "Match whole word only" under Smart Highlighting.

That seemed to work for me.

[image]

Comment: This sounds incredibly promising but I cannot test it out until tomorrow but if it works then I will gladly accept this answer!

Comment: Superb, thank you so much for the answer!!

Comment: This setting has honestly made Notepad++ so much nicer for me and it will be so much harder to ever give it up for any other editor. I sincerely appreciate this answer and wish I could upvote several times.

Comment: Agreed @MonkeyZeus, what an improvement. Highlighting `.` and `"` and other punctuation is also now possible - even spaces!

Comment: I tried to insert [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgwPI.png) but the edit was rejected. Paul Van Bommel or @MonkeyZeus, maybe you want to add it?

Answer (score 8):

#### With my cursor I wish to select $hey_ and have the 3 $hey_s highlighted

Select the text `$hey_` and then Menu > Search > Mark All > Choose a highlight style:

[image]

Comment: Hi, just wanted to let you know that I have accepted a different answer to my question. Your answer works properly for my issue but the other answer wins due to ease-of-use. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer and other are good but I needed to adjust few style to highlight it properly so that it can standout as my default Global override has foreground and background white and black respectively

Settings -> style Configurator -> Global Styles

Then change foreground color and background for below Style as needed:

Selected text color
Smart HighLighting
Mark Style 1 to 5